# how would you write the 'last' function using 'accumulate'?

Tags: scheme

I've been working on the sicp and am trying to write the 'last' function using accumulate

```
(define (accumulate f x xs)
  (if (null? xs)
      x
      (f (car xs)
         (accumulate f x (cdr xs)))))

 (last '(1 2 3 4 5)) ;;=> (5)
```

---

I tried this but it does not work

```
 (define (last seq)
   (accumulate (lambda (x y) x)
               '()
               seq))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (last lst)
  (accumulate (lambda (x y)
                (if (null? y)
                    (cons x y)
                    y))
              '() lst))
```